# Saving fragment position into textures

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, cg

I would like to store my fragment's world coordinates into 3 textures which respectively represent x,y,z coordinates of the coordinate. Despite the textures are in the format ARGB32, I cant seem to write a value bigger than 1.0 Here is my shader code. What is the proper way to do this?

```
Shader "Custom/FirstPass"
{
    Properties { }

        SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM

            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 5.0

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct vertexData
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float3 normal : NORMAL;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float4 texcoord0 : TEXCOORD0;

                //...
            };

            struct fragmentData
            {
                float4 positionC : SV_POSITION;
                float4 positionW : TEXCOORD1;


                //float4 color : COLOR;
                //...
            };
            struct fragmentOutput
            {
                float Gx : SV_Target0;
                float Gy : SV_Target1;
                float Gz : SV_Target2;
                float depth:SV_Target3;

            };

            fragmentData vert(vertexData v)
            {
                fragmentData o;
                o.positionW=mul(unity_ObjectToWorld,v.vertex);
                o.positionC=UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fragmentOutput frag(fragmentData fragment)
            {
                fragmentOutput output;
                output.Gx =fragment.positionW.x;
                output.Gy= fragment.positionW.y;
                output.Gz = fragment.positionW.z;
                output.depth=fragment.positionC.z;

                //... write to other renderbuffers

                return output;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```